# grep loses coloring when run from bash script

Tags: bash, colors, grep

I wrote a simple bash script because I was using a grep command with the same arguments, repeatedly. I'm running it from ~/bin and it runs just fine.

**My problem is**: All the coloring is gone when it's run through my bash script. The exact same command put right into the commandline nicely color codes line numbers, filenames, etc.

Here's my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
# grep php files inside of myfolder, recursively and with line numbers

grep -rn --include="*.php" "$2" /home/me/myfolder/$1
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You've probably defined `grep` as an alias for `grep --color=auto` in your `.bashrc`, but that's not loaded by scripts. Use an explicit `grep --color` in your script.

Comment: Adding `--color=always` in the script did it for me

Comment: `--colour` works too for UK mates out there.

Answer (score 4):

When you run a script, a new shell is spawned to do so.  This new environment doesn't have the same settings as your default shell.  As to how to get the coloring back, I'm not sure.  You might try sourcing your profile at the start of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

or whichever file makes sense on your particular unix flavor (.profile, .bash_rc, .bashrc .bash_profile) to name a few.

Comment: I tried this with 'source $HOME/.bashrc' and 'source $HOME/.profile' but it didn't work for me. I was really hoping this would be the solution so that I wouldn't have to explicitly state things like '--color', or any other unforeseeable params, in future scripts.

Comment: You can export the option to the environment of the script: `export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'`

Comment: It helped me to find another solution, in the beginning of the script add `-i` : `#!/bin/bash -i` It loads the default shell settings