# Why does grep lose colored output when executed from a bash script?

Tags: bash, colors, grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [grep loses coloring when run from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550885/grep-loses-coloring-when-run-from-bash-script)

I have a simple bash script to print a header on top of my `grep` results:

```
#!/bin/bash

for var in "$@"
do
    if [[ $var != -* ]];
    then
        break 
    fi
done

echo
echo -en "\e[1;31m     ====== GREP $var ======\e[0m\n"
echo

grep $@
```

But the final command is somehow not the same as actually running `grep` from the prompt directly, because the colors are missing from the results. When executing `grep` directly, the results show filenames in purple and matches in red, but now all the output is the normal terminal text color. Can someone tell me how to get the colored version from my script?

Comment: Hint: How does `grep` know to output colours in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried `--color=always`?

Comment: yeah, it's basically a duplicate... my bad.

Comment: BTW, `grep $@` should be `grep "$@"` to avoid changing `grep "foo bar"` to `grep foo bar`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like grep does not produce colors when not in interactive mode. You can force it to produce colored output:

```
grep --color=always $@
```

Comment: Needs to be `grep --color=always "$@"` to avoid breaking quoting in the original command.

Answer (score 10):

Grep has 3 color modes, Auto, Always, and Off.

Auto strips out the codes when it's connected to a non interactive output, such as a pipe (if you want to see why, try redirecting the output of `grep --color=always` into a file and then look at the file.. control codes everywhere)

Comment: I found the grep --color and --colour options are always, never and auto. And I found never to be useful when the input to grep was already colorized which I wanted preserved to the output.