# Create alias for grep on Mac terminal

Tags: hash, terminal, grep, alias

I usually run this command to verify a SHA1 hash of a file

```
shasum filename.txt |grep -E --color '<hash value>|$'
```

So I created an alias for it:

```
alias shacheck='check_sha_hash'

check_sha_hash() {
    shasum $1 |grep -E --color '$2|$'
}
```

But it didn't help:

```
shacheck myfile.txt 3a5b106e413ab621ad13788e5ceab8ba1d974cb8
3a5b106e413ab621ad13788e5ceab8ba1d974cb8  myfile.txt --> didn't colorized the hash
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Where have you defined the alias and the function, on your _current_ terminal session or in any of the start-up files, e.g. `.bashrc`?

Comment: yes in `.bashrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *forcing* colored output like this:

```
check_sha_hash() {
    shasum $1 | grep -E --color=always "$2|$"
}
```

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12321791/819340) for more information.

Comment: Gotcha. It's because of the fact that in my alias `alias shacheck='check_sha_hash'`, I used the single quote. In the function `check_sha_hash', I used single quote too, which break the `grep` Stupid me. Anyway, I'll mark this as the answer since it helped.